# Too many FB share button request

Tags: performance, facebook, optimization, share

I'm optimizing my site speed. One of the main issue I'm facing is the homepage.

In the homepage, each article has FB/TW share buttons.
I only inserted the scripts in the footer once but I'm getting bunch of FB/TW share button requests[image: see the requests].

Is it normal or there is something I need to do?

Comment: The Facebook social plugins work by inserting iframes into your document, and the content of those iframes is then loaded via the GET requests you see …

Comment: Is it necessary that all of these requests should be loaded when I visit the homepage? What I understand is that GET should only happens when you click the share button. Am I right?

Comment: No, the content of the iframe – the actual “like” and the count number that you see – needs to be loaded before that. When you click the button, that will trigger _another_ request …

Answer (score 0):

For every Like/Share button that you have, your browser needs to make a request to get the content. This is only executed when the browser has received the page from your server, so it does not affect the initial load time.

As CBroe mentions, the button is displayed in an iFrame. These are loaded and depending on your browser settings all at the same time or consecutive. During this time, your browser is not blocked so your used can already interact with the page.

If you want to reduce load, the only option is to remove the buttons. I think you have some index/home page where you load all the articles and for each of those a button? You could consider only showing the buttons on the articles itself, if you are really concerned about this.

But, since this is normal behaviour and your page is not blocked by loading all the iframes, this is not a big issue nor can you optimise it yourself.